# Open a record, update it and insert as new record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a db with 10 fields, of which only a few change very often. I would like to open the current record, update it, and enter it back into the db with a new auto id while retaining the previous record.

If I INSERT a new record, I have to re-enter all the info even tho it may not have changed.
If I UPDATE a record, it overwrites the previous values.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: Correct, when you insert records, which you're doing in this case, you have to set values for all columns that you don't want default values for. What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a suitably modified version of

```
insert into table select * from table where id='current_id'
```

Sample query:Say i want to read first record ,lift student, subject but change marks and insert a new record

```
insert into score(student,subject,marks) 
select student,subject,'30' from score where id=1;


Sample Data
+---------+---------+-------+----+
| student | subject | marks | id |
+---------+---------+-------+----+
| A1      | phy     |    20 |  1 |
| A1      | bio     |    87 |  2 |
| A2      | che     |    24 |  3 |
| A3      | che     |    50 |  4 |

Table structure:

+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| student | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| subject | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| marks   | int(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id      | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM table`. Note that `*` implies you have no primary key column(s) that will create a duplicate key. This would be rare. Most likely, you will need to name the columns.

Comment: @MarcusAdams .. Edited to make things clearer... hope the example makes things clearer..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via two different queries: SELECT and INSERT, or you can use INSERT INTO SELECT construction. Check documentation for complete reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html